# How to give helpdesk users read-only access in Active Directory on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, active-directory, user-accounts

We are using Active Directory on a Windows Server 2012 R2. All employees are using a desktop with Windows 7 which is connected to the domain. Our 1st line helpdesk users don't have access to Active Directory on the Windows Server and they never get this access.

We would like to give the helpdesk users read only access in Active Directory in Windows 7. The target is it needs to be possible for them to check if someones user is locked or not. How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: All domain users by default have read-only access to the domain. Simply install the dsa.msc tool on their computer. If you want grant them access to unlock users, DO NOT GIVE domain admin access, just use OU "access delegation"

Comment: No we dont want to give them access to unlock locked users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They already have read-only access (every domain user does unless you specifically take it away). Just have them install the Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT): https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=7887

Then they can run AD Users and Computers (dsa.msc) from their own machine.